# Prove that a sequence has at least three partial limits.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let  $a_n$ be a sequence. suppose $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<2$ for every $n$.

given $lim\inf_{n\longrightarrow\infty}a_{n}\leq1$ and $lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\sup a_{n}\geq4$.

Prove:  the sequence has at least three Subsequential limits.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to form a subsequence that must alternate between being close-ish to the infimum and supremum. In order to get from one side to the other the subsequence must bounce in the interval. The points that fall in the middle have a subsequence that converges, and we will guarantee that this sequence does not converge to the infimum or supremum.

By definition of infimum, for all $\epsilon > 0$, for any $N$ (no matter how large) we may find a $k\geq N$ such that 
$$a_k -\operatorname{lim\,inf}_n a_n < \epsilon$$

Rearranging and applying the inequality we get
$$\operatorname{lim\,inf}_n a_n \leq a_k < \operatorname{lim\,inf}_n a_n + \epsilon \leq 1 + \epsilon$$

Similarly, for the supremum, we find
$$4-\epsilon < a_k \leq \operatorname{lim\,sup}_n a_n $$

Fix some $\epsilon$ such that $\tfrac12 \geq \epsilon > 0$ (the decision of upper bound will become apparent shortly, but is necessary here as we are fixing $\epsilon$).

Using these guarantees we may construct an index sequence inductively over $k$ as follows:

- For $2k$, define $n_{2k}$ to be a number such that $a_{n_{2k}} < 1+\epsilon$ and $n_{2k} > n_{2k-1}$.
- For $2k+1$, define $n_{2k+1}$ to be a number such that $a_{n_{2k+1}} > 4-\epsilon$ and $n_{2k+1} > n_{2k}$.

We will show that for each $k$ there exists an index $r_k$ between $n_{2k}$ and $n_{2k+1}$ such that
$$1+\epsilon\leq a_{r_k}\leq 4-\epsilon.$$

By the definition of the subsequence, $a_{n_{2k}} < 1+\epsilon$, and so
$$a_{n_{2k}+1} = \underbrace{a_{n_{2k}+1}-a_{n_{2k}}}_{\leq |a_{n_{2k}+1}-a_{n_{2k}}|} + a_{n_{2k}} < 2 + (1+\epsilon) = 3+\epsilon \leq 4-\epsilon$$
where the right-most inequality follows from the upper bound on $\epsilon$.

Hence $a_{n_{2k}+1}\not \geq 4-\epsilon$, and if $a_{n_{2k}+1} \geq 1+\epsilon$ then we are done (take $r_k = n_{2k}+1$) otherwise $a_{n_{2k}+1} < 1+\epsilon$. Continuing inductively, we must find an $r_k$ as otherwise, for all $i\colon\, n_{2k}\leq i \leq n_{2k+1}$, $a_i < 1+\epsilon$, contradicting the definition of $n_{2k+1}$ (as $a_{n_{2k+1}} > 4-\epsilon$ by construction).

Finally, as $\left\{r_k\right\}$ is a bounded sequence, it has a convergent subsequence that converges to some limit $\ell\in[1+\epsilon,4-\epsilon]$ and

$$\operatorname{lim\,inf}_n a_n \leq 1 < 1+\epsilon \leq \ell \leq 4-\epsilon < 4 \leq \operatorname{lim\,sup}_n a_n$$

So $\operatorname{lim\,inf}_n a_n$, $\ell$, and $\operatorname{lim\,sup}_n a_n$ are distinct partial limits.

Comment: Can you please explain how you concluded that ark is between 4-epsilon and 1+epsilon?

Comment: I have modified my answer to make this clearer. Essentially we are are always able to find an $r_k$ for which $n_{2k} < r_k < n_{2k+1}$ and $1+\epsilon \leq r_k \leq 4-\epsilon$.

Comment: is it possible to solve this question by saying: we shall want to find a sub-sequence of $a_{n}$, suppose it to be $a_{n_{k}}$ . If there's an infinite number of objects of $a_{n}$ in s.t: $1\leq a_{n_{k}}\leq4$, than we will get a contradiction to the claim assuming there's only infinite number of $a_{n} $ objects  for $1\geq a_{n}$ and $a_{n}\geq4$.

Comment: @Jneven I don't quite follow. It is perfectly possible that every single $a_n$ satisfies $1< a_n < 4$, e.g., $a_n = \begin{cases}1+1/n & \text{for $n\equiv 0 \operatorname{mod} 4$}\\
4-1/n & \text{for $n\equiv 2 \operatorname{mod} 4$}\\
2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

Recall this standard result:

> $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is the largest subsequential limit of the sequence $a_n$.
>
> $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n$ is the smallest subsequential limit of the sequence $a_n$.

Since $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n \geq 4$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq 1$, this means that $a_n$ has at least one subsequential limit greater than or equal to $4$, and at least one subsequential limit less than or equal to $1$.

It remains to find a third subsequential limit.

---

To make progress, I would prove the following:

> **Lemma:** For all $N \in \mathbb N$, there exists an $n \geq N$ such that $a_n \in [\tfrac 3 2, \tfrac 7 2]$.

*Proof:* Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $a_n \notin [\tfrac 3 2, \tfrac 7 2]$.

- $a_n$ has a subsequence that tends to $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n$, which is less than or equal to $1$. Therefore, there exists an $n_1 \geq N$ such that $a_{n_1} \in (-\infty, \tfrac 3 2)$. By induction, one can prove that $a_{n'} \in (-\infty, \tfrac 3 2)$ for all $n' \geq n_1$. (You'll need to use the fact that  $|a_{m+1} - a_{m}| < 2$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$ to prove the inductive step.)
- $a_n$ has a subsequence that tends to $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$, which is greater than or equal to $4$. So there exists an $n_2 \geq N$ such that $a_{n_2} \in (\tfrac 7 2, \infty)$. By similar reasoning, one can prove that $a_{n'} \in (\tfrac 7 2, \infty)$ for all $n' \geq n_2$.

These two bullet points are contradictory. Indeed, defining $n := \max \{ n_1, n_2 \}$, we have $a_n \in (-\infty, \tfrac 3 2) \cap (\tfrac 7 2, \infty) = \emptyset$, which is absurd.

---

Our Lemma shows that $a_n$ has infinitely many terms that lie in the interval $[\tfrac 3 2, \tfrac 7 2]$. From this, we may deduce that $a_n$ has a subsequence $b_k := a_{n_k}$ such that $b_k \in [\tfrac 3 2, \tfrac 7 2]$.

So $\liminf_{k \to \infty} b_k$ and $\limsup_{k \to \infty} b_k$ are both in $[\tfrac 3 2, \tfrac 7 2]$. Therefore, $b_k$ (and therefore $a_n$) has a subsequential limit between $\tfrac 3 2$ and $\tfrac 7 2$, and we're done.