# Partial limits - writing a formal proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $\left|a_{n+1}-a_{n}\right|<2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\limsup}\left(a_{n}\right)\geq4$, and $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\liminf}\left(a_{n}\right)\leq 1$. Prove that $a_n$ has at least three partial limits.

First, I tried to show that the sequence has at least two partial limits because the $\limsup$ is not equal to the $\liminf$. Then I tried to show that because the distance between any two consecutive elements is less than $2$, there should be another partial limit between $1$ and $4$, but I have a problem with writing this formally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a sequence has at least three partial limits.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542463/prove-that-a-sequence-has-at-least-three-partial-limits)